# Asbestos in bathroom cornice?

Tags: plaster, trim, asbestos, stucco

Does anybody know if asbestos was used in cornice? Could the fibres in the pictures be asbestos?

The construction year is '86 (South Europe).

I know it's better to have it tested than asking, but for a series of reason it'll take me a long time to do that and thought I might ease my mind till then.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like glass fibre reinforcing mesh, but that doesn't definitely mean there's no asbestos-based material in there

Comment: Probably low possibility.  As long as you don't sand or scrape it and have fibres floating around, you should okay with a decent mask and eye goggles.  Painting or removing in clunks should be safe to do.  Breathing in loose tiny fibres for a long time is the dangerous part.

Comment: @crip659 "long time" - I talked to workers who played "snowballs" with asbestos insulation while they worked years ago (sadly they are all carrying oxy tanks around or popping their clogs)... A one-off sanding job - really...

Comment: Get it tested to be sure. But **any** dust is not good so use masks etc